# Power Automate refresh excel file with Power Query

Tags: power-automate-desktop

I created a flow in Power Automate Desktop that allows to open an excel file in SharePoint, refresh it and close it. My concern is that it's closing it too fast. I know that it takes few minutes to refresh it.

Is there another step that I need to add after the data gets refreshed? (wait for system etc)

Thanks

I tried to run the workflow but it's running fast and I suspect that data does not get completely refreshed, it normally takes longer if I manually open the file and refresh it.

Comment: Did you check if the data is actually modified correctly or not after you run the workflow?

Comment: I checked the data and it's not fully updated. Normally it takes up to 5 mins for data to be refreshed. For now I keep the file open and I removed the step where Excel has to be closed because the system doing it right away. I wonder if there's anything else I can do to give a system at least 5 mins to refresh and then close by itself